# QGIS - Unable to Create New Shapefile

Tags: qgis

I am running Windows 7, QGIS 3.12.3 Bucuresti and hitting a wall trying to create a new shapefile. I have georeferenced (GeoTIFF) imagery and I want to create polygons that cover forested areas within the imagery in order to assign a particular forest type (coniferous, deciduous, etc.) in an area in Eastern U.S. This will be used to import into FlightGear as new Scenery that will populate the tree(s) into the scenery. I ran across a "How To" article (http://wiki.flightgear.org/Howto:Create_custom_terrain) that appeared to cover what I want to do, but I believe it's based on a very, very old version of QGIS (1.X).

I may be approaching this wrong, but I select Create New Shapefile Layer, give it a unique name, select Polygon, and add a new field called "Class" (Text Data) and add it to the Fields List. With both the respective imagery and the just-created Shapefile in the Layers window (made sure that the CRS was the same in both), I left click on the Shapefile, then right-click, select Toggle Editing, then draw the polygon on the visible imagery. I believe that after the last point is selected, I should "right click" and the polygon should remain visible. However, nothing happens. However, if I select the Imagery file, then do the same, the polygon disappears and I get the following error: "No active vector layer: To select features, choose a vector layer in the layers panel." In the instructions in the above "How To", it never mentioned creating a Vector layer.

Any info, or a pointer to a more up to date tutorial?

Comment: Windows 7 is not supported by Microsoft, anymore is there a reason you cannot use Windows 10?

Comment: After you right click you should see a popup asking you for an ID for the polygon. It may be that this popup is getting lost behind the QGIS UI so try minimising after right click

Comment: You can check in the attribute table of the vector layer if the feature was (or not) created. If it is created, make sure an appropriate style is set and that the vector layer is above the image layer

Comment: Mapperz - I've been trying to hold off on pushing to Windos 10, primarily because I own an early version of Presagis Stage that is not compatible with 10. May have to bite the bullet and buy another PC...

Comment: CitizenFish - Didn't think of that, so will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: JGH - That may be the issue. But what's the appropriate order? Do I create a new Shapefile first, and is it a Vector or Raster and then open the primary GeoTiff image that the Shapefile encompasses? I already have the Landcover data that will be used to map to particular species of vegetation/trees...

Comment: Shapefile is a vector layer.. geotiff is a raster layer.

Comment: Neogeomat - Yes, that's true. The question then would be if I want to designate/draw specific polygonal areas within a GeoTiff image and specify certain types of vegetation that, when rendered, are visible in, say a FlightGear Scenery file, would that then be a Vector layer? This is where I get a bit lost...